# Iterate over ManyToMany field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am having some problems with iterating over a ManyToMany field.
I want to have a Post and Tag model, and have the Post model extend the Tag model in the form of a ManyToMany relation.

Below are both my `Tag` and `Post` models.

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = RichTextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,default="",max_length=1000)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='tags',blank=True)

    # .... other non related functions
```

However, when I am in the Django shell, I can't seem to loop over these tags, despite the object having tags associated to it.

For example, I would do `post1 = Post.objects.all()[0]`, and then `post1.tag.name.all()`, however it would give me an error saying `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'`

Everything else I have tried failed. What can I fix to solve the issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove the `.name`!

Comment: Make this an answer and I mark it as correct. I cannot I didn't think of that lmao
Thanks once again!

Answer (score 5):

You are suppose to iterate through tags object like this

```
for tag in post1.tag.all():
   print(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to iterate over ManyToManyField

```
for tag in post1.tag.all():
   print(tag.name)
```

Other than iteration, I have some other suggestions. Like
`tag` will have many tags so naming it `tags` is more suitable. Secondly related_name is **The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one** So in your case it should be `posts` instead of `tags`

So it will look like

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts', blank=True)
```

Now you can access posts from any specific tag using this related_name. For example, If you have tag

```
tag1 = Tag.objects.all()[0]
```

Now you can get all posts with this tag using following line

```
tag1_posts = tag1.posts.all()
```